# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecs_logging'

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Successfull instal ecs-logging 2.0.0, but after import module in python scrypt get error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecs_logging'

How to solve that?

Trying for import ecs-logging get error import ecs-logging SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you remember how do you install the module on the terminal, for example `python -m pip install ecs-logging`?

Comment: install module using pip install ecs-logging

Comment: Hi,
Please try use `python -m pip install esc-logging`, or even version-specified `python3.x -m pip install esc-logging` while x is the minor version e.g. (11 in Python 3.11)